# What's wrong with this assembly code? I'm getting an unknown register error

Tags: assembly, x86

What's wrong with this? I don't see an error here. It tells me unknown register, but since I know little to nothing about assembly, I don't really know the problem.

```
;  Clicking button saves & builds using commands:
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs evil.asm
;    ld -o evil evil.o
section .data
Snippet: db "@E9>06G@Q:CN3C57I<)<)*"
SnipLen: equ $-Snippet
section .text
global _start
_start:
        nop
        mov ecx,Snippet
        mov edx,SnipLen
        mov eax,6
DoMore: add byte [ecx],af
        inc ecx
        inc eax
        dec edx
        jnz DoMore
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        sub ecx,SnipLen
        mov edx,SnipLen
        int 80H
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80H
        nop
```

Comment: There is no register named `af`.

Comment: What should I replace it with?

Comment: It's ah since it's byte sized. If you know little to no assembly, you should start learning assembly if you're going to code assembly...

Comment: @redguard001 It depends on what you want this code to do.  I suppose you wrote it; what did you think when you wrote this line?  What did you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
DoMore: add byte [ecx],af
```

The instruction allows for one argument to be register or memory, and the other is register only (in either order). Since `[ecx]` uses indirection syntax, it is clearly the "memory" usage, and the other parameter must be the name of a register.

I don't see any data label value `af` in your listing, if that's what you intended.  But that won't work anyway, as the other argument must be a simple register name only.

---

## update

You seem confused as to what you should write, in the comments.
Since you loaded `eax` with 6, I suspect you wanted to add 6 to where `[ecx]` is pointing, adding the next number to each byte in turn.  In this case, you meant **`al`**, the low byte making up `eax`.

Comment: Looking at the `byte` size tag, my first guess was for a (wrongly written) immediate operand. BTW you don't mention that possibility in your 1st paragraph. You even seem to exclude it totally? The update nails it, I think. +1

Comment: @SepRoland it didn't occur to me that it might be a hex literal.  But he is loading and updating `eax` that's not used for anything else, so that seemed to be what the code needed.